# Android ics-Openvpn

Tags: ics-openvpn

I'm building the open source project https://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/

The readme file says: "Disable Google breakcode (WITH_BREAKPAD=0 in jni/Android.mk)"

how can I perform this action?

Answer (score 2):

GO jni folder Open Android.mk and search WITH_BREAKPAD .. when you find it .. it would be like WITH_BREAKPAD=1 make it WITH_BREAKPAD=1 
hence resolved

Comment: *WITH_BREAKPAD=1* has to be replaced with *WITH_BREAKPAD=0*